# Cannot deploy Managed VM: SSL CA certs error

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Cannot deploy Managed VM to AppEngine:

```
$ gcloud preview app --project=myproj deploy .
12:17 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 209, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 205, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 621, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1088, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/exceptions.py", line 86, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/deploy.py", line 114, in Run
    push.PrepareVmRuntime(runner)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/push.py", line 41, in PrepareVmRuntime
    output = runner.Run('prepare_vm_runtime')
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appengine_adapter.py", line 281, in Run
    error_code = app.Run()
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appcfg/appcfg.py", line 2847, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appcfg/appcfg.py", line 4347, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appcfg/appcfg.py", line 3874, in PrepareVmRuntimeAction
    app_id=self.options.app_id)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/external/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 220, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 129, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 533, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1608, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1350, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1036, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/Users/anentropic/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 891, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 507, in __init__
    self._context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an environment-specific issue caused by a release on Wednesday. There are more details here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=130

Let me know if updating again fixes the issue. If not, please attach the output of "gcloud info".

Comment: is there a correct procedure for reinstalling?  I did `gcloud components reinstall` but I still get the error. my `gcloud info` returns: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xyVz9y9a

Comment: This seems to be specific to python 2.7.9. I'm trying to track down the engineer who worked on the fix, but in the meantime you can use this to roll back to the last version:

export CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_SNAPSHOT_URL=http://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-v0.9.55.json
gcloud components update

Comment: in case it's relevant, I currently have TLS turned off in my boot2docker Docker daemon due to other problems with Py 2.7.9/SSL/Homebrew https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/38226

Comment: still, must be related to recent gcloud update because I had TLS turned off before and was able to get much further in my deployment, this current problem is new

Comment: Yeah, this was definitely related to the update. It's caused by a difference in behavior between Python 2.7.6 and 2.7.9. We'll have a fix out this week. Until then, you can roll back using the steps above.

Comment: The roll back worked for me. Puttin the preview in preview ;0 Thanks dlorenc.

Comment: This should be fixed as of yesterday's release (0.9.57). For future reference, this is a better way to rollback/freeze your gcloud state:
gcloud config set --scope=installation component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.55
gcloud components update